# SQL script to find index's tablespace_name only

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Trying to find the specific tablespace names that were created for indexes only. I don't want to see the tablespaces names that are already used for tables.

Something like below, but i couldn't have it working due to syntax error. Can someone fix it?

```
select tablespace_name
from dba_indexes
where tablespace_name NOT EXISTS (select distinct tablespace_name
                                  from dba_tables
                                  where owner like 'USER')
  and owner like 'USER'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DTA.*
FROM DBA_TABLESPACES DTA,
  dba_indexes DI
WHERE DI.TABLESPACE_NAME = DTA.TABLESPACE_NAME
AND DI.OWNER             ='USER'
AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 'x'
  FROM DBA_TABLES DTT
  WHERE DTT.TABLESPACE_NAME = DTA.TABLESPACE_NAME
  AND DTT.OWNER             = DI.OWNER
  );
```

Comment: The `Schema` *USER* doesn't have any index only tablespace. Can you you try removing the `owner='USER'` condition.